# VS Code Dart/Flutter listing @override marked methods in implements?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, overriding, intellisense

I couldn't list overridable methods in VSCode for Flutter/Dart project. Look to below image.

[image]

GetxController class includes many @override marked methods. For example : onClose, onStart etc..

The VSCode intellisense doesn't list the this methods when I press to CTRL+space.

But, when I type first letter of method, it's listing the GetxController methods. Look to below image.

[image]

I didnt find any extension for list avaliable @override marked methods. No solution...

I don't want to type a letter for list them. I want to list them like Visual Studio. May be with a magic usage (like @override blablabla... + Enter).